# Getting an error in spring application: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am getting an error while running my Spring application. Here is my qtServlet-servlet xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:component-scan base-package="jp.co.vmt.qt" />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

And I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/qtServlet-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 130; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
```

I have declared this in my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.0'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadSources=true
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.4.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.4.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.4.RELEASE'
//      compile 'org.springframework:spring:2.5.6'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.4.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.4.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
//          compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'
        compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA'
        compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
        compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.2.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.4.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.2.4.RELEASE'
    }
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'


// JDK version source compatibility
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
// project version
version = '1.0'
// War file name
war.baseName = 'WebGradle'
// Web directory, this overrides the default value "webapp"
project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

// Set source directory
sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }

// dependencies to run on tomcat, are mandatory for tomcat plugin
dependencies {
    def tomcatVersion = '7.0.57'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
    }


}

// context where tomcat is deployed, by defautl localhost:8080/
tomcatRun.contextPath = '/'
tomcatRunWar.contextPath = '/'
```

I think I properly declared the correct dependencies and versions in both my qtServlet-servlet.xml as well as in build.gradle but I am getting the said error. I have verified that the jar files are in my build path as well as the deployment path of tomcat. I'm not sure what's causing the error as similar questions say just incorrect versions of the xsds to the one declared in the depencencies. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the version info from the schema locations.

Try this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out when I tried to access the schema locations with my browser and found out they don't exist, so I changed it to a version that exists.